# Proving $(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My attempt goes like this: Let $R = (a_1, b_1) \times \cdots \times (a_n, b_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x\in R$, $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$. Because $x\in R$ we can say that, for all $i\in I_n = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, $a_i < x_i < b_i$.

Consider $$r = \min_{i \,\in \, In} \{x_i - a_i, b_i - x_i\}$$ That is, $r$ is the minimum distance from $x$ to a "wall" of the "polytope" $R$. Note that $r$ is positive, because $x\in R$. Taking into account this $r$, now consider $B(x;r) = \{a\in \mathbb{R} \;\vert\; d(x,a) < r\}$. In order to prove that $x$ is interior to $R$, we must prove that $B(x;r) \subseteq R$. Let $y\in B(x;r)$, $y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$. Because $y\in B(x;r)$, 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
d(x,y) & < & r \\
\displaystyle \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - y_k)^2} & < & r \\
\end{array}$$

And from here I don't know where to go. I tried considering a case $r = x_i - a_i$ for some $i \in I_n$, but I could only prove that $a_i < y_i$ for that particular $i$. And if I want to prove that $y\in R$, I must show that $ a_j \leq y_i \leq b_j$ for all $j\in I_n$. **Any tips?**

Comment: Using the distance formula makes it harder than it needs to be. In particular, $y\in B(x;r)$ implies that $|x_i-y_i| < r$ for each $i$ separately. This reduces it to the one-dimensional problem: does an open interval of radius $r$ about $x_i$ lie inside the interval $[a_i, b_i]$? (Answer: yes, by your choice of $r$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof might be slightly easier if instead of letting $r$ being the minimum that you defined above, you let it be less than the minimum of those quantities.  I will assume that $r$ is less than the minimum.  First observe that $|x_i - y_i| < r$ for each $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ since if any one of them were greater than or equal to $r$ then this would violate the fact that $y \in B(x;r)$ since

$$
|x_i - y_i| \;\; \leq \;\; \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2 }.
$$

Observe we can rearrange this to write $|x_i - y_i| = |y_i - x_i|$.  Then we have that

$$
-r \;\; < \;\; y_i - x_i \;\; < \;\; r
$$

hence

$$
x_i - r \;\; < \;\; y_i \;\; < \;\; x_i + r
$$

but $a_i < x_i - r$ and $x_i + r < b_i$, hence $y_i \in (a_i, b_i)$.